# Jquery .size() problem and self executing closure problem

Tags: jquery

I am facing a problem with jquery and have a question. Please answer them (I am a newbie to jquery).

**Question 1:**

In this html structure:

```
<div id="main">
        <div id="abc" width="78px" value="no vla">xyyyyyyyy</div>
        <div id="ppp" width="78px">zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</div>
</div>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$.fn.hilight = function(a) {

  alert($('div').size());
};

alert('before');

$('').hilight(89);

</script>
```

$('div').size() Output is showing 4. But there are 3 divs here. What i am missing ? I checked in firebug for Div tags and found 3 div there. Please help :-(

**Question 2:**

How self executing closure works ? I mean, when we write:

(function(A){document.write(A);})(jQuery);

does jQuery object is passed into the function ? if i write "abcd" instead of jQuery then parameter A gets the value "abcd". in this case, second () pass value to first () (function i mean)..............With concept of C/C++ it matches ? there is no return here, so i am bit confused.

Comment: You must have something more on your page 'cause it alerts **3** You can see it here : http://www.jsfiddle.net/8xzLs/

Comment: i am unable to sort out the problem in my pc as i triple checked in firebug :-( ........anyways, i consider it's just a bug for my pc so i continue assuming nothing happened. what about the second question ?

Comment: forgot to thank........Thanks clem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding yoru second question:

its not so much a self executing closure, but a function declaration and call.

```
(function(A){document.write(A);})(jQuery);
```

can be broken down to

```
var f = function(A){document.write(A);}
f(jQuery);
```

Same thing.